# Concat PChar with string in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, pointers, delphi-2010

I need to construct a string and send it via `PostMessage`, ie.

```
FileName := String_1 + String_2 + String_3;
PostMessage(FWndHandle, WM_BLA_BLA, NotifyData^.Action, LParam(FileName));
```

but something isn't working. Plus, FileName is a PChar. The code looks like this:

```
var
   FileName : PChar;
   Directory_Str : String;
   AnotherString : String;
begin
    // Get memory for filename and fill it with data
    GetMem(FileName, NotifyData^.FileNameLength + SizeOf(WideChar));
    Move(NotifyData^.FileName, Pointer(FileName)^, NotifyData^.FileNameLength);
    PWord(Cardinal(FileName) + NotifyData^.FileNameLength)^ := 0;

    // TODO: Contact string before sending message
    // FileName := AnotherString + Directory_Str + FileName;

    PostMessage(FWndHandle, WM_BLA_BLA, NotifyData^.Action, LParam(FileName));

    ...
end;
```

Now I need to do contact another string to the variable `FileName` before calling `PostMessage`, ie.

```
FileName := AnotherString + Directory_Str + FileName;
PostMessage(FWndHandle, WM_BLA_BLA, NotifyData^.Action, LParam(FileName));
```

This would work if FileName was a string, which is not the case here.

**Anyone knows how to do that with PChar?** I tried these methods, works sometimes but always something breaks at the end:

```
StrPCopy(FileName, FDirectory + String(FileName));
```

OR

```
FileName := PChar(AnotherString + Directory_Str + FileName);
```

Comment: What does "something isn't working" and "always something breaks at the end" mean? What **specific** problem are you having? Why are you using `PChar` and `GetMem` at all? (IOW, why are you mixing the types in the first place?)

Comment: One problem with PostMessaging strings is that the strings tend to get destroyed whe nthey go out of scope before they are received in the target thread/window - PostMessage just communicates the pointer, it knows nothing about the refCount on the string and so does not increment it.

Comment: @MartinJames Which is why the code in the question allocates the buffer with `GetMem`.

Comment: @KenWhite: You're absolutely right, it was *really* late and I just typed the question quickly without going into details, but David got it and its solution worked just fine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot easily use `PostMessage` with data passed by reference. The reason being that `PostMessage` executes asynchronously and you need to keep the memory you are passing alive until the message has been processed by its recipient. I guess that's what is behind your `GetMem` code.

Obviously this only works within the same process. And you will also find that Windows won't let you use `PostMessage` for any of its messages that receive pointers. For example, `PostMessage` with `WM_SETTEXT` always fails. You can only hope to do this using a user-defined message. And of course you'll need to deallocate the memory in the code that receives the message.

I'm going to assume that you are using a user defined message that does allow sending a string with `PostMessage`. In which case you already have the solution. Do the concatenation using string variables and then use the first block of code in your answer.

Although you can make it much cleaner like this:

```
function HeapAllocatedPChar(const Value: string): PChar;
var
  bufferSize: Integer;
begin
  bufferSize := (Length(Value)+1)*SizeOf(Char);
  GetMem(Result, bufferSize);
  Move(PChar(Value)^, Result^, bufferSize);
end;

procedure PostString(Window: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; 
  const Value: string);
var
  P: PChar;
begin
  P := HeapAllocatedPChar(Value);
  if not PostMessage(Window, Msg, wParam, LPARAM(P)) then
    FreeMem(P);
end;
```

And you can just call that procedure like this:

```
PostString(FWndHandle, WM_BLA_BLA, NotifyData^.Action, FDirectory + FileName);
```

Your current code fails because:

1. When you call `StrPCopy` you don't allocate any memory for the longer string.
2. When you write `PChar(AnotherString + Directory_Str + FileName)` you fall into the trap of that you were trying to avoid with `GetMem`. That's a local string which has been deallocated by the time the message is processed.

If you can find a way of solving your problem without using `PostMessage` to pass a string, that might be preferable to all this complexity.

Comment: This is a great example of why it pays to separate code into small functional parts. By mixing up the GetMem/buffer copying code alongside the message posting code, it becomes harder to re-work that code. But the the trivial expedient of separating the concerns into separate functions, suddenly it becomes easy. Of course, hindsight always makes it easier to see the right functional decomposition. But always be alive to such issues and be on the look out for better factoring of your code.

Answer (score 6):

See David's answer for reasons why your code fails.

I always define a class for distributing strings through `PostMessage` operations.
No risk of leaks and it's easy to expand with more information.

```
Type
  TMyMessage = class
    msg : String;
    Constructor Create(aMessage : String);
  end;


// Sending the message
var
  myMsg : TMyMessage;
...
myMsg := TMyMessage.Create('A message');

if not PostMessage(someHandle,WM_something,WParam(myMsg),0)
then begin
  myMsg.free;
  ... Take care of this condition if PostMessage fails !!
end;  

// Receiving the message

procedure TSomeForm.GetMessage(var msg : TMessage);
var
  aMsg : TMyMessage;
begin
  ...
  aMsg := TMyMessage(msg.WParam);
  try
    ...
    // Do something with the message
  finally
    aMsg.Free;
  end;
end;
```